# MySQL Daily Time Coverage Without Gaps

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like the following example: 
[image]

What I need to do is return the coverage (number of hours an operator/s were onsite) for each day. The challenge is that I need to ignore gaps in coverage and not double count hours where two operators were signed in at the same time. For instance, the image below is a visual representation of the table.
[image]

The logic of the image is as follows:

- Operator A: Signed in at 10 and signed out at noon for a total of 2 hours
- Operator B: Signed in at 1 and signed out at 3 for a total of 2 hours
- Operator A: Came back and signed in at 2 and signed out at 5 for a total of 3 hours but 1 hour overlaps with operator A so I cannot count that 1 hour otherwise I will be double counting coverage

Therefore the total coverage time without overlaps is 6 hours and the value I need the query to produce. So far I can ignore double counting by taking the max in min dates of each day and subtracting the two:

```
SELECT YEAR, WEEK, SUM(HOURS)
FROM
(SELECT 
  YEAR(SignedIn) AS YEAR, 
  WEEK(SignedIn) AS WEEK, 
  DAY(SignedIn) AS DAY,
  time_to_sec(timediff(MAX(SignedOut), MIN(SignedIn)))/ 3600 AS HOURS
 FROM OperatorLogs
 GROUP BY YEAR, WEEK, DAY) As VirtualTable
GROUP BY YEAR, WEEK
```

Which produces 7 because it takes the first sign-in (10 AM) and calculates the hours up until the last sign-out (4:00 PM). However, it includes the gap in coverage (12 - 1) which should not be included. I am unsure of how to remove that time from the total hours while also not double counting when there is overlap, i.e. from 2-3 there should only be 1 hour of coverage even though two separate operators are on site each putting in an hour. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is it always two operators, or can there be any number?

Comment: It can be any number

Comment: Will every row have a time in and a time out, or can they be NULL?

Comment: Will the time in and time out always be on the same day?

Comment: Every row will have a time in and time out except for the current day i.e. someone signed in but has not yet signed out for the day.

Comment: The time in and out will be on the same day

Comment: You you need the edge case code for "today", where you only count the coverage up to "now"?  *(so if someone signed in this morning at 10am, and it's now 4pm, the coverage is 6 hours?)*

Comment: I don't need the edge case for today. Essentially assume that there are no NULL values.

Comment: MySQL makes this less straight forward (no analytic functions, unless you're using MySQL 8?), thinking about the least messy and least expensive way to do it.

Comment: Agreed. I can do it easily if I can write some logic using a secondary language (e.g. Ruby, Java, etc.) but unfortunately the client that needs this has very antiquated systems and I only have access to an old MySQL Database

Comment: Taking on board questions and comments thus far provided, see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry I am not sure how your comment is relevant to my question. I show the data, I show the desired result, and I show what I have thus far. Plus is a very simplified version. Why the downvote?

Comment: Actually you didn't show the desired result of the SQL query, nor the current output from your attempt. The spreadsheet picture shows something else, not the output of the code in question.

Comment: @ADyson I say "Therefore the total coverage time without overlaps is 7 hours and the value I need" does this not convey that I need the query to return 7 and why? I also say "the image below is a visual representation of the table" which I would think implies that it's not the output of the code in question. The thing I agree with is that i don't show the output of my current attempt, but very few Stackoverflow questions do. I just looked at some of the highest voted questions and none of them do.

Comment: I'm not bothered but, as I see it, there's your way, and there's my way. How's your way working out?

Comment: @Strawberry who said you were bothered? I was trying to understand and improve, hence the question of why the downvote. My way leans towards explanation and helping people. Your way seems to be the way of quick punishment. In terms of hows it working out, it cost me 2 imaginary points :) so not sure what you are trying to get at.

Comment: Now now children, you both have valid points.  The question does have most of the necessary information, and still it could be better.  My point of view is that perfection is not required for it to be good enough to elicit a good enough answer.

Comment: @MatBailie I guess we'll never know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, work interrupted me.

Here's my working solution, I'm not convinced it's optimal due to the (relatively) expensive nature of the joins, but I've optimised it slightly based on the soft-rule that "shifts" never span multiple days.

```
SELECT
  calendar_date,
  SUM(coverage_seconds) / 3600   AS coverage_hours
FROM
(  
  -- Signins that didn't happen within another operators shift
  SELECT DISTINCT
    DATE(e.signedin)                          AS calendar_date,
    -(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(e.signedin) MOD 86400)   AS coverage_seconds
  FROM
    OperatorLogs   e
  LEFT JOIN
    OperatorLogs   o
      ON  o.signedin  >= DATE(e.signedin)
      AND o.signedin  <       e.signedin
      AND o.signedout >=      e.signedin
  WHERE
    o.signedin IS NULL

  UNION ALL

  -- Signouts that didn't happen within another operators shift
  SELECT DISTINCT
    DATE(e.signedout)                          AS calendar_date,
    +(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(e.signedout) MOD 86400)   AS coverage_seconds
  FROM
    OperatorLogs   e
  LEFT JOIN
    OperatorLogs   o
      ON  o.signedin  >= DATE(e.signedout)
      AND o.signedin  <=      e.signedout
      AND o.signedout >       e.signedout
  WHERE
    o.signedin IS NULL
)
  AS coverage_markers
GROUP BY
  calendar_date
;
```

Feel free to test it with more rigourous data...

- https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4RgWVhcdNEro21rUksVdXD/0

*(As a note, to make your sample data match your excel image, your first shift should have started at 9am)*

Comment: Wow. Much appreciated! I will test first thing in the morning.

Comment: @Darkisa - You're welcome, hope it helps or sets you in the right direction.

Comment: Still not fully sure how you did it but it works :). I'm definitely gonna spend some time studying what you did. And good catch. I updated the question in regards to your note. Thanks for your time MatBailie!